# Does a larger coefficient of variation mean larger variability?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I'm reviewing right now for an exam and I've stumbled across [this](http://ncalculators.com/math-worksheets/coefficient-variation-example.htm) online reviewer. In the solution for question #2 **it stated that Section B is more consistent so there is greater variability in the wages of section A**.

```
Coefficient of variance for Section A = 7/450 x 100 =1.56 % 
Coefficient of variance for Section B = 9/350 x 100 = 2.57%
```

My answer is the opposite, that section B is less consistent and there is less variability in section A. Am I correct or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I agree with you that Section B has both a higher standard deviation and a higher coefficient of variation (note is it called this, rather than *coefficient of variance*) so there is greater variability in the wages of section B, not section A.

Answer (score 1):

The sample coefficient of variation is the sample standard deviation
divided by the sample mean.

Here is an illustration: Which has greater variability, weights
of elephants or weights of ants. In terms of the standard deviation
the answer has to be elephants because they weigh more. Dividing
by the mean tends to put the two measures of variability on the
'same scale'. In terms of the coefficient of variation, the answer
is probably ants. Some species of ants are several times larger
than others. So relative to their small size, ants may be considered
more variable.

Put in another way, the sample SD and sample mean have the same units. This means the coefficient of variation (CV) is a 'dimensionless'
measure of variability. So even if elephants are weighed in tons
and ants in grams, the CVs have no units and can be compared
directly. (You might want to read parts of the
Wikipedia article on 'coefficient of variation'.)

Finally, I wonder how you are computing the CV in your example. Could you be
confusing the variance and the SD?